# Problems With WP Bannarize Plugin

Tags: plugins

I’ve been troubleshooting multiple issues on the above website, and now I’m down to 1 final issue. The site’s supposed to display banner ads, but on mobile devices, the ads do not display, instead the raw shortcodes show up instead. The ads do display normally on desktop/laptop devices however.

I can confirm it’s not just my device as my client reported it to me when he experienced it while in the middle of a call. I checked for myself and found the same issue he was reporting.

I would have posted this to the support forum for that plugin, but I saw others have reported issues there over the past year that have gone totally unanswered. This plugin appears to have been abandoned by the developers so I’m hoping the general WP community might have some suggestions on how I could fix this issue.

I’m hoping someone might have a simple fix I can implement and save my client the expense of switching to a new plugin for now.

The page I need help with: http://www.theafronews.com

EDIT: It's been suggested I seek help on this issue at wordpress.org. I have been trying to get help there for days now and am getting nowhere over there. I've had 2 different attempts to get an answer to this issue over there locked almost right away by a moderator claiming this question duplicates a years old, locked, and obviously unrelated topic. This is getting extremely frustrating and I'm just wanting to reach out to a WordPress community to get some help or suggestions.

At this point, I'm looking for any advice on anything I can do to get my client's website displaying ads properly across all devices, anything I can recommend to him at all.

Comment: It looks like you're using a plugin that's been abandoned, WP Stack Exchange isn't a place you can get support for abandoned plugins or unresponsive developers though. I'd suggest going to a user group or the .org forums

Comment: I tried posting in the org forums, and got nowhere. In the plugin sub forum, nobody's getting answered, and in the main forums, the mods have closed my question twice now, both times claiming I'm duplicating some old topic that has nothing to do this this question that I posted years ago. That's why I came here to see if anyone can suggest anything. I can't afford to keep my client waiting 6+ months for nobody to answer.

Comment: Can you please re-instate this topic? I really need to get some help on this and can't get it where you suggested. Getting blocked every 2 seconds by moderators giving me the runaround is getting frustrating in the extreme.

Comment: **This is not a place for 3rd party plugin support**, you can argue your case on the meta sub-site, but the rules are clear, 3rd party plugin support is not in scope, and is off topic. Hence the closure. If somebody has directed you here for that, then they shouldn't have done so. Keep in mind too that most close votes come from active users of the site, not moderators, and this is your first and only question and interaction with moderation.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try to use:

> **[Smart Slider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-slider-3/) / [WP Booststrap Gallery](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-bootstrap-gallery/)**

Are great plugins for Banner, they are free, responsive and easy to adapt.

---

**Here's an example of using SmartSlider with ShortCode:**

```
<section id="secao-sliders-index">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
      <div id="container">
        <?php 
        echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider=2]');
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
      <div id="container">
        <?php 
        echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider=3]');
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-6"> 
      <?php 
      get_template_part('_xxx'); 
      ?>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6"> 
      <?php
      get_template_part('_xxx');
      ?>      
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

**Here the banners dashboard:**

[image]

Comment: Answers need to be self contained, you can't just recommend a plugin and link to it. Plugin recommendation questions are also out of scope, and get closed. Better to spend your time on high quality answers to interesting questions in order to gain upvotes and encourage good community behaviour

Comment: Does that plugin allow banner ads to be placed anywhere via widget or shortcode? My client needs ads in 3 places on the site, at the top of every page, in the sidebar, and at the top of all articles. The ads need to rotate randomly to display 1 ad and be split by category as each type of ad has a different cost associated with it. I'm hoping to avoid changing plugins if there's any way to keep using WP Bannarize even a few months more, as my client doesn't have a lot of money to spend on more work, and if we change plugins, that will mean migrating all ads to the new plugin.

Comment: Yes they can @RadiantFreedom, both via ShortCode and you can easily edit them any way you want

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm sorry if I did it wrong, I'm new to the community, my goal in the answer was never to win or lose points, but to try to help the friend with problems, he asked for help to anyone who could help him, but he did not find it in other places. So I indicated plugins that I use and never had problems.

Comment: Commenting with a plugin link might work, but otherwise you're signing yourself up for making sure the answer doesn't die from bitrot and the plugin remains functional. Don't worry though, we all make mistakes early on, just remember the format here is Q&A and not a discussion forum, and you can always ask for advice on how to write answers, or what to do in situations. We've chat rooms and the meta site too

Comment: @Gabriel Carneiro - That's for expanding on your answer. Yes, that plugin does look like something I could recommend to my client as a possible replacement for the dead plugin. It's looking more and more like migrating his ads to a new plugin may be the best solution.